# Cannot install XML::LibXML module on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, xpath, cpan, xml-libxml

I am trying to use `XPath` to extract some HTML tags and data and for that I need to use `XML::LibXML` module.

I tried installing it from CPAN shell but it doesn't install.

I followed the instructions from CPAN site about the installation, that we need to install `libxml2`, `iconv` and `zlib` wrappers before installing `XML::LibXML` and it didn't work out.

Also, if there is any other simpler module that gets my task done, please let me know.

The task at hand:

I am searching for a specific `<dd>` tag on a html page which is really big ( around 5000 - 10000) `<dd>` and `<dt>` tags. So, I am writing a script which matches the content within `<dd>` tag and fetches the content within the corresponding (next) `<dt>` tag.

I wish i could i have been a little more clearer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need more detail. What is the error you're getting from the CPAN shell install?

Comment: Can you show us how you are trying to install it?

Comment: ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl? Which version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using ActiveState Perl, you should add the repositories listed at [ActivePerl 10xx Win32 PPM packages](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/PPMPackages/10xx/) to `ppm` and then use

```
ppm install XML::LibXML
```

Trying to parse HTML as XML is generally not a pleasant task. I think [HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TokeParser) is more suitable to the task.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new(\*DATA);

my @definitions;

while ( my $dl_tag = $p->get_tag('dl') ) {
    while ( my $dt_tag = $p->get_tag('dt') ) {
        my $term = $p->get_trimmed_text('/dt');
        my $dd_tag = $p->get_tag('dd');
        my $defn = $p->get_trimmed_text('/dd');
        push @definitions, [$term, $defn];
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@definitions;

__DATA__
<dl>
<dt>One</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Two</dt>
<dd>2</dd>
</dl>
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'One',
            '1'
          ],
          [
            'Two',
            '2'
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want XPath queries then I just wrote a script yesterday that uses XML::XPath::XMLParser to do XPath queries on an xml file.

I have tested it with both Activestate's perl installation and with strawberry perl on windows.

I don't remember having to go to cpan to install any modules( though I may have earlier and forgot doing so:)), so perhaps you can use the XML::XPath module instead?

Here is the sample from the documentation

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'test.xhtml');

my $nodeset = $xp->find('/html/body/p'); # find all paragraphs

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    print "FOUND\n\n", 
        XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node),
        "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Since it is unlikely you will get Win32 versions of libxml2, iconv, and zlib (although they exist, see http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html for example) to work with the XML::LibXml module, I think chollida's approach sounds better.

Comment: @ewall - give some context.  chollida's approach is better than what?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using ActiveState Perl, you can get [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML) working just fine.
You can get XML::LibXML from [Randy Kobes' site](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/dist/XML-LibXML) and you get libxslt/libxml, etc from [zlatkovic.com](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html)

I just install libxml first and then use ppm to install XML::LibXML. Works just fine.

If you are using [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com), CPAN should work for you as libxml2, etc are part of the Strawberry Perl distribution I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Also see my post in the thread [How do I install XML::LibXML for ActivePerl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900681/1084592).

Discusses some issues/solutions I encountered installing XML-LibXML using PPM.