# How do I install XML::LibXML for ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, activeperl, xml-libxml

I am new to Perl and I am using [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/).
I am getting the following error:

> Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC...

I have tried everything but cannot find the steps to install the "correct" module for XML::LibXML.

Here is exactly what is going on. I am running a script from a command prompt:

> c:\temp>perl myscript.pl

The first few lines of myscript.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
use HTTP::Date;
use XML::Parser;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use XML::LibXML;
use Archive::Extract;
use Encode;
use LWP::Simple;

require HTTP::Request;
...
```

Then I get this error:

> c:\temp>perl myscript.pl Can't locate
>   XML/LibXML.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at
>   myscript.pl line 7. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at
>   myscript.pl line 7

Comment: Are you trying to use XML::LibXML directly, or is this a dependency of another module you're using?

Comment: I added some more details above. I have added the packabe libxml using the activeperl package manager

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to install it with the [ActivePerl Perl Package Manager](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Downloads/ActivePerl/PPM/).  There should have been a start menu shortcut created when you installed ActivePerl, start [the GUI](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_gui) and search for xml-libxml and libxml-perl.

--edit

[Here's a post on adding an alternative repository to PPM and installing XML-LibXML](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=798219)

Comment: Thanks, But I installed "libxml-perl" from the "ActivePerl Package Manager" and I still get the same error. I checked the details and that package does not install LibXML.pm Here is a screen shot http://bit.ly/cf3av

Comment: Try searching for xml-libxml.

Comment: Nope nothing is coming up... I added some more details to the question. thanks!

Comment: This package is currently available with the package manager: I just installed it.

Comment: xml-libxml does not install a LibXML.pm for me. Using ActivePerl 5.16 and PPM 4.17. Unfortunately the theoryx5 repo in the forum link returns 503 errors.

Comment: Apparently there's no LibXML.pm on 5.16. See my answer below for fix.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like ActiveState provide a PPM with XML::LibXML. I looked in the README for the module on CPAN and apparently a prebuild ppm package is available [here](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/PPMPackages/10xx/).

Comment: above link is 503 error for me, but sources available from cpan here http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3ALibXML

Answer (score 2):

I have recently been through the pains of getting XML::LibXML installed.  Here is what I found:

1. We are using ActiveState ActivePerl 5.8.8
2. In order for ActivePerl's PPM to get through our proxy, had to create an environment variable "http_proxy" with value "http://proxy.ext.[example].com", then re-login.
3. The required packages weren't all located in ActiveState's repository.  Added University of Winnipeg's Perl Repository http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/package.xml (note that the exact repository used depends on your version of ActivePerl)
4. Manually install the following DLLs into C:\perl\bin\ (for whatever reason, I was having some trouble building these DLLs, so I ended up simply grabbing them from the repository at http://trouchelle.com/ppm/dll/ )

   - iconv.dll
   - libxml2.dll
   - zlib1.dll
5. At least for the version of XML-LibXML we are using, the package installer doesn't work correctly for the prerequisite XML-LibXML-Common.  You ***MUST*** install the package XML-LibXML-Common by itself, ***BEFORE*** installing the rest of XML-LibXML.

Although they may not be the latest versions, the versions of the packages (including prerequisites) which I am currently using are:

- XML-LibXML-Common (ver 0.13)
- XML-LibXML (ver 1.64)
- XML-NamespaceSupport (ver 1.10)
- XML-SAX (ver 0.96)

Comment: I have the same issue today. Did you just copy those 3 .dll in the folder C:\Perl\bin\ ? Using search from ppm, it only returns libxml-perl [0.08] libxml-perl

Comment: Yes, I just copied those 3 DLLs which I described.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer didn't work for me on 5.16. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801989/perl-xmllibxml-not-accessible-anymore-as-package-windows):

> XML::LibXML was not ready for Perl 5.16. Install **5.14**

Download:

- [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads)
- [StrawberryPerl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the only alternative ActivePerl repository in existence, as far as I can tell, and it had a package for XML::LibXML 2.0121 which will install on perl versions up to 5.20.x.

You can obtain releases of ActivePerl from here that includes 5.20.2: downloads.activestate.com/ActivePerl/releases/

The alternative repository is called Bribes de Perl at bribes.org/perl/

The URL of the repository that is entered in options is http://bribes.org/perl/ppm/