# Is XML::LibXML not supported on Perl 5.8.8?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074154/extract-xml-tags-using-perl/5076794#5076794) on SO a while back where I initially suggested using XML::DOM. After [mirod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11095/mirod) suggested that I use XML::LibXML instead, I implemented it. And to be honest, it works great on my system. I saw my runtime drop drastically with the new module without doing any additional optimizations.

Now the tricky part, for some reason the module doesn't even install on my colleagues system.

> ppm install xml-libxml returns:
>   Downloading ActiveState Package
>   Repository packlist...not modified ppm
>   install failed: Can't find any package
>   that provide xml-libxml

The only difference I could find between the two machines was that I was using AS Perl v5.12.1 and he is on AS perl V5.8.8.

Is xml-libxml supported on AS Perl v5.8.8?

Also, I visited the Active State [PPM index](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-LibXML/) and that seems to indicate that its broken on 5.8 all the way through to 5.12.

Does anybody have any experience with this module?
Should I roll back to XML::DOM - which with its slow performance and not being actively maintained, at least installed and worked?

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: ActiveState does sometimes incorrectly marks a distribution as failing, when in-fact there is nothing actually wrong. Unfortunately this means you can't even force, it to install, because it is compiled on their system, not yours.

Comment: Thanks Brad, so do I have any options other than to proceed with installing AS Perl 5.12? Also, why does it install on my machine on 5.12 even though its marked as a failed build on 5.12?

Comment: It has been years since I've use ActiveState Perl. I now compile my own Perl's. If your using Windows, I would recommend using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but AS perl is what is mandated by the org and deployed in the standard image. I don't have a say in deciding to go with a different distribution all together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that I have to add a repository, like the uwinnipeg repo http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/, when I am trying to install XML-LibXML on windows. Might be your problem too.

Comment: When I was stuck with Active Perl 5.8, I found with Winnipeg site and the Trouchelle.com site indispensable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though, I will use this as a workaround for now. However, with 5.12.1 on my local, I didn't have to add a new repository and still it worked. Thats the part which confuses me. I would prefer to fix the root cause than move to choosing workarounds.

Comment: Btw, I am going ahead and accepting this as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://kobesearch.cpan.org/ to find repositories that have your desired ppms.

Answer (score 0):

Also see my post on [a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900681/1084592) regarding how I was able to install XML-LibXML with ActivePerl 5.8.8.

In short, you can find the appropriate package in the corresponding uwinnipeg repository.  *NOTE see http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/ for the correct repository version to use*, and XML-LibXML-Common ***MUST*** be installed first.  Also, make sure you have the prerequisite DLLs installed before installing XML-LibXML via PPM.