# Why can't cpan install XML::LibXML?

Tags: perl, cpan

This is really weird, can someone explain why GCC can not find an include file when installing [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML)?

```
> cpan PAJAS/XML-LibXML-1.70.tar.gz
...
C:/CPANTE~1/PERL51~1.0_6/site/bin/gcc.exe -c    -DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -O2 -DVERSION=\"1.70\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.70\"  "-IC:\CPANTesters\Perl5.16.0_64\lib\CORE"  -DHAVE_UTF8 -DHAVE_BLANK LibXML.c
LibXML.xs:34:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

> IF EXIST %INCLUDE%\libxml\xmlversion.h ECHO Cogito ergo sum
Cogito ergo sum
```

This is ActiveState 5.16.0 64 bit with MinGW64.

I decide to drop using Zlatkovic Win32 binaries ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/, and use the 64 bit binaries available at http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/dependencies/.

The problem above is solved by going to the unpacked module and execute this command:

```
> perl Makefile.PL INC=-IC:\CPANTesters\bin\gnome-deps-win64\include LIBS=-LC:\CPANTesters\bin\gnome-deps-win64\lib
> dmake
```

But problem arises from running dmake test since Perl crashes on all test files.

```
C:\CPANTesters\Perl5.16.0_64\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/01basic.t ......................... Dubious, test returned 38 (wstat 9728, 0x2600)
Failed 3/3 subtests
```

Any idea on how to debug this?

Comment: Do you need to pass `-I%INCLUDE%` to GCC?

Answer (score 3):

[XML-LibXML](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) is a Perl binding for [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/), but it does not include a copy of libxml2 (of which `libxml/xmlversion.h` is a part).  You must install that separately, and make sure Perl and `gcc` can find it.  `INCLUDE` is not an [environment variable used by `gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html).  It uses `CPATH` or `C_INCLUDE_PATH`.

I contributed [instructions for installing XML-LibXML from source on Microsoft Windows](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0004/README#L126).  Did you try following them?

The easiest way to get XML-LibXML on Windows is to install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).  It comes with XML-LibXML in the package.

Comment: I have tried using C_INCLUDE_PATH and the error message is gone, but I encountered other problems. Since the title is changed to "Why can't cpan install XML::LibXML?", I'll expand the article to fully reflect the whole experiment.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 by first running `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` and when that completed, I was able to run `sudo cpan install XML::LibXML` with success.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, on windows, the easiest thing is to use a repository that has built LibXML for you.
This question is similar to yours: [Is XML::LibXML not supported on Perl 5.8.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396126/is-xmllibxml-not-supported-on-perl-5-8-8/5396888#5396888)

Answer (score -1):

try this, it worked for me on centos 6, after doing this I was able to install via CPANM other modules relying on XML::LibXML https://www.question-defense.com/2010/01/27/perl-cpan-install-xmllibxmlcommon-error-libxml2-not-found