# Perl XML::LibXML installation failing

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I'm trying to install Perl XML::LibXML module through CPAN but getting the following error.
I'm using Windows 7 machine and Perl v5.16.1. I did lot of search but didn't get any solution.

What should be the problem?

```
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
enable native perl UTF8
Checking for ability to link against xml2...no
Checking for ability to link against libxml2...libxml2, zlib, and/or the Math library (-lm) have not been found.
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from
  http://xmlsoft.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.

Also, you may try to run perl Makefile.PL with the DEBUG=1 parameter
to see the exact reason why the detection of libxml2 installation
failed or why Makefile.PL was not able to compile a test program.
**No 'Makefile' created  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0014.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK**
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
**Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites**
Failed during this command:
 SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0014.tar.gz             : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

Comment: Do you have libxml2 installed? Including the header files?

Comment: I don't have libxml2 installed with me.

Comment: On windows, it is easier to use a repository that has the full module and dependencies bundled with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396126/is-xmllibxml-not-supported-on-perl-5-8-8/5396888#5396888

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear which Perl distribution you are using. On Windows, it is easiest to use [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) and its native package manager `ppm` (not CPAN).

On my Windows 7 machine, I was able to install `XML::LibXML` without any problem using this command:

```
ppm install XML::LibXML
```

Comment: I was using ActivePerl and was trying to install XML::LibXML from CPAN shell, I also tried using native PPM but got no success.

I just changed my distribution to Strawberry Perl that solved the issue.

Comment: Using CPAN from within ActivePerl does not work very well (especially for modules requiring C code or libraries like libxml2). For ActivePerl, using `ppm update`, `ppm install <module>` works 99% of the time

Answer (score 0):

For ActivePerl on Windows, XML::LibXML is not available through PPM anymore due to missing dependencies which must be manually installed.

Installing through CPAN is the right way, but you need to make sure libxml2 and its dependencies are present. They are required by XML::LibXML.

The installation (taken from [here](https://www.opswat.com/blog/installing-libxml-perl-module-microsoft-windows), thanks to Rudy Rodriguez) is a long and winding road, but it works (Win 8.1, ActivePerl 5.20.1 x64):

- Get the required binary package of libxml2, iconv, zlib (all from [here](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html)) and [gettext-tools](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win64/dependencies/gettext-tools-dev_0.18.1.1-2_win64.zip).
- Extract all files into the same directory (e.g. C:\perl_libxml\merged) so that files in the include, lib etc. subdirectories within each zip file are extracted to one common include, lib etc. directory
- move the /libxml2/libxml folder one level up, i.e. to /libxml, as this is the expected default directory
- rename libz.a to zlib.a (in the lib dir)
- install the dependencies

  ```
  ppm install dmake MinGW XML::NamespaceSupport XML::SAX
  ```
- add c:\perl_libxml\merged\bin to the Windows PATH
- go to the directory where the failed cpan build resides, e.g. c:\perl64\cpan\build\XML-LibXML<...>
- run:

  ```
  Makefile.PL INC=-IC:\perl_libxml\merged\include LIBS=-LC:\perl_libxml\merged\lib
  ```

  The build of the Makefile should succeed. If not, check if the LIBS and INC parameter point to the right directory
- ```
  dmake
  ```

  If this fails, check if your path entry is properly set
- ```
  dmake test
  ```

  If 'dmake test' fails with cryptic errors like:

  ```
  load_file:%1 is not a valid Win32 application at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 191
  ```

  it may be that different versions of some of the libraries are present in your PATH and therefore linked during build.

  I had another MinGW environment in my PATH leading to a linking of the wrong libs. I could resolve it by examining the built libxml.dll with the 'depends' tool from [Windows Server 2003 platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12261). You can see which DLL is used by libxml.dll and what platform is was compiled for. All of these must match and also match your Perl version, either x86 or x64.
- If the tests succeeds, finally install XML::LibXML with

  ```
  dmake install
  ```

Sidenote: I know this question is quite old but I put this solution here as a reference for others running into the same issue in the future (maybe me being one of them...).

Answer (score 0):

Install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), it comes with XML::LibXML and its dependencies built-in.