# Perl XML::libxml not accessible anymore as package ? (windows)

Tags: xml, perl, package, libxml2

I was not able to install on a windows system from the graphical `Perl Package Manager`

I'm running `Perl 5.16`, I've added the repository uwinnipeg but it seems to be not available anymore.

http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/dist/XML-LibXML  is unavailable

What can I do to get `XML::libxml` work on`Perl 5.16` (windows) system ?

Comment: Going on the ActiveState site: http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-LibXML/, you can see that the build failed for ActivePerl 5.16.  In other words it is probably not available.  Unless you're tied to ActivePerl for some reason, consider moving to Strawberry Perl instead (http://strawberryperl.com/).  It allows you to use standard CPAN modules on Windows, making life a whole lot easier.

Comment: It's failing because the underlying library isn't on the system.

Comment: @dan1111, `cpan` works perfectly fine with ActivePerl. Switching to Strawberry Perl doesn't add anything. At best, it's the same as ActivePerl. At worse, you can't use PPM.

Comment: @ikegami, last I used ActivePerl, installing modules from `cpan` that need C compilation was problematic, because the compiler environment was not present.  Strawberry Perl includes a compiler environment that works out of the box.  In my opinion, that is a big difference (also, Strawberry Perl is open source; ActivePerl has a free version but with a limited license).

Comment: @dan1111, `cpan` installs a C compiler if needed. The same one Strawberry ships with.

Comment: I just installed to ActivePerl 5.16 x64 fine with a "cpan XML::LibXML"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because XML::LibXML was not ready for Perl 5.16 (either Active Perl or Strawberry Perl), I installed Perl 5.14 and XML:LibXML was back in the ppm graphical window. I installed from there...

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling XML::LibXML from CPAN using instructions that included making zlib1.dll, iconv.dll and xmlm2.dll in your path or else use the command

`perl Makefile.PL INC=-Ic:\perl_libxml\include LIBS=-Lc:\perl_libxml\lib`

It failed to compile with a dmake error 129 about xmlm2.dll.  I assume that I was using a version of xmlm2.dll incompatible with XML::LibXML 2.0121.

In the end I found the only alternative ActivePerl repository in existence, as far as I can tell, and it had a package for XML::LibXML 2.0121 which will install on perl versions up to 5.20.x.

You can obtain releases of ActivePerl from here that includes 5.20.2: http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePerl/releases/

The alternative repository is called Bribes de Perl at bribes.org/perl/

The URL of the repository that is entered in ActivePerl options is http://bribes.org/perl/ppm/